# how to add multiple conditions in unique property laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, validation

Table : charges

```
id | ac_id | year |
| - | -- |-------------- |
| 1 | 1  | 2021          |
| 2 | 1  | 2020          |
| 3 | 2  | 2021          |
| 4 | 2  | 2020          |
```

I am having a problem  while doing validation, the year should be unique with respect to the ac_id

```
 'year'=>"required|unique:charges,year",
```

This validation rule I tried but not working while adding the same year for different ac_id

Comment: There is no built in feature in this situation. Let us see your Custom Validation rule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using where in your [validation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique) rule:

```
 'year' =>['required', Rule::unique('charges')->where(function ($query) {
                    return $query->where('ac_id', $this->get('ac_id'));
    })]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be enforcing this at the database table level using a unique constraint:

```sql
ALTER TABLE charges ADD CONSTRAINT c_unique UNIQUE KEY (ac_id, year);
```

Comment: This is a completely valid answer, and this sort of thing is much better handled at the database level versus the application code.